# Why can't I read push message data in Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have a problem that I cannot read the push message data at this time. I get a message normally.

I can receive both when the app is in Foreground or Background when I press the Home button.

But I can't see the message data in the log.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate  {
...
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
       guard
           let aps = data[AnyHashable("notification")] as? NSDictionary,
           let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
           let body = alert["body"] as? String,
           let title = alert["title"] as? String
           else {
               // handle any error here
               return
           }

       Log.Info("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")
       Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(data)

      // Print full message.
      Log.Info(data)
    }
...



    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

          Log.Info("fcmToken \(fcmToken)")
       }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
           Log.Info("remort \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
```

**Data I Send**

```
{

     notification : {

                            "title" : "test title.",  

                            "body" : "test context."            

                      },

     data : {

                    "image" : "http://11.111.111.111:100000000/_img/sample_01.jpg",  

                    "page_url" : "http://11.111.111.111:100000000/Point?address=",   

                    "type" : "point"       

             }

}
```

Logs cannot be viewed in any function. What am I missing? Please let me know what's wrong.

---

**EDIT**

---

I modified the wrong data and changed the location of the log. But I don't have any logs on me.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Print full message.
        Log.Info(data)
       guard
           let aps = data[AnyHashable("notification")] as? NSDictionary,
           let body = aps["body"] as? String,
           let title = aps["title"] as? String
           else {
               // handle any error here
               return
           }

       Log.Info("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")
       Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(data)
    }
```

**send test message in firebase**

[image]

I have two `messaging` functions in addition to `application` functions of the application. Are these message functions not needed by me? These functions have never shown me a log.

Comment: I don’t see a key “alert” in your data and use a swift dictionary instead of NSDictionary

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson That's right, but I can't even see the full data. 'Log.Info(data)'

Comment: Move that log statement to the start of the function, if the guard statement fails it will exit and the rest is not executed

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Please look at the question that I modified.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have two message functions besides application function. Is this not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved this problem using a different function.

I solved it using a different function, but I wish there was another good solution.

I wonder what the fundamental problem was. This is just another alternative.

```swift
    @available(iOS 10, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let data = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        guard
            let aps = data[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
            let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
            let body = alert["body"] as? String
            else {
                Log.Error("it's not good data")
                return
        }


        Log.Info(body)

        completionHandler()
    }
```

Comment: This is not an alternative, this is the way it should be done since iOS10

Answer (score 1):

The method that you are using was deprecated in iOS 10.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application

The Notifications framework replaced this method with the updated one from iOS 10 onwards:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

More details of the Notifications framework are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications)